# Перетаскивание OpenStreetMaps сквозь блок

Tags: javascript, css, leafletjs

У меня поверх карты OpenStreetMaps находится div. И когда карта перемещается мышкой, то она так же перемещается сквозь блок. Блок как будто прозрачный. Мне нужно, чтоб блок при наведении на него принимал эвенты мышки, а карта не двигалась.
Используется также LeafletJS

Comment: по всей видимости у блока стоит свойство - `pointer-events:none`

Comment: pointer-events:auto тоже не помогает

Comment: а `pointer-events:auto!important` ?

Comment: ну о нем и речь. вроде получилось в компьютерной версии сделать, что хотел. но в мобильной все равно не работает